# Java textBox.setText() error (too much text?)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, methods, settext

I have a total noob Java question :|
When using the setText() method, I get this error

```
javax.swing.JTextArea[,0,-26524,590x27015,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicBorders$MarginBorder@52d1f1fb,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],colums=20,columWidth=11,rows=5,rowHeight=15,word=false,wrap=false]
```

And this is my action event

```
    list.setText(list.toString().replaceAll("|3835569365|e49e24d5", ""));
```

list is my JTextArea, those numbers and hex as well as the | are what I'm basically trying to remove from the text area.

Thanks anyone :)

Comment: that's... not an error

Comment: I don't see any error message anywhere. All I see is the standard `toString()` representation of a JTextArea. PErhaps you want instead to call `getText()` on the JTextArea.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you are using `toString()` when you should using `getText()`.

Change your code to read more like...

```
list.setText(list.getText().replaceAll("|3835569365|e49e24d5", ""));
```

Instead

`toString()` is returning stateful information about the object, you shouldn't need to use in every day work

Comment: Also the regex is faulty, the vertical bars need escaping as they're metacharacters. "\\|3835569365\\|e49e24d5" would make them literal.

Comment: @ChrisMcMorran Welcome to my normal world :P

Comment: @ChrisMcMorran And mine, and most other programmers' :P